# WordPress: style.css, footer.php и второе меню

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день. Есть такой код на второе меню (дабы вставить в footer.php):

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size:16px; ">
<a href="http://localhost/site/" style="color: #867550;">На главную</a>  |  
<a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/" style="color: #867550;">О компании</a>  |  
<a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/" style="color: #867550;">Раскрытие информации</a>  |  Закупки  |  
<a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0/" style="color: #867550;">Вакансии</a>  |
```

Есть такой пар-тр в style:

## colophon {

margin-bottom: 20px;
background: #E8E8E8;
padding: 20px;

В общем в шаблоне в футере блок (серого цвета) в котором копирайты и тд. Как туда воткнуть код html. Потому что если использовать footer.php то вставляется (меню) либо выше серого блока, либо ниже. А мне надо чуть ли не в плотную (либо сверху либо снизу) (но обязательно в этот серый блок воткнуть)

Comment: Скинь ссылку на сайт пожалуйста

Comment: К сожаления не могу. На локальном компе делаю пока =(

Comment: Может быть поможет название темы для WP? я сильно ничего не менял. Только цвета в CSS в основном.

Comment: Вы когда вставляете этот код в Footer.php, выше или ниже среднего серого блока получается, значит вы его вставляете выше или ниже какого то кода. Скиньте в вопрос этот код.

Comment: Валерий. Спасибо за помощь. Справился сам. Той же логикой руководствовался что и вы (искал этот код). Оказалось что в WP (по крайней мере в моей теме) существует два php footer. Во втором нашелся, дорогой :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вставляете свой код, выше или ниже функции которая выводит серый блок. Нужно найти код серого блока в другом файле вашей темы и вставить свой код внутри его.